# Recursive function with table values

Tags: postgresql, recursion, fibonacci

I have a table `evenfib` that looks like this:

| id | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 1000 |

I need to get sum of all even Fibonacci numbers that are lower than the given number `n`
I figured out how to get a fiboacci sequence with static limitation, but I can't understand how to use it with values from the table.

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.0 and here is the code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE fibonacci(prev_n, n) AS (
  SELECT 0::bigint, 1::bigint
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n, prev_n + n AS fib FROM fibonacci WHERE n < 100
)

SELECT SUM(prev_n)::INT
FROM fibonacci
WHERE prev_n % 2 = 0
```

This code returns 44 (0.44e2 without casting as INT) and it works well because Fibonacci sequence below 100 is 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89, so 2 + 8 + 34 = 44.

But I want to be able to change 100 in the end of line 4 to values from an `evenfib` table.

Comment: Write an SQL function with your statement in it and the limit as parameter.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
WITH RECURSIVE fibonacci(id, prev_n, n) AS (
  SELECT id, 0::bigint, 1::bigint
  FROM evenfib
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, fib.n, fib.prev_n + fib.n
  FROM fibonacci fib
  JOIN evenfib USING (id)
  WHERE fib.n < evenfib.n
)

SELECT id, SUM(prev_n)::INT
FROM fibonacci
WHERE prev_n % 2 = 0
GROUP BY id;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XrbrW-HS))</sup>

Alternatively, just use a subquery on `evenfibs` instead of the static limitation:

```
WITH RECURSIVE fibonacci(prev_n, n) AS (
  SELECT 0::bigint, 1::bigint
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n, prev_n + n
  FROM fibonacci
  WHERE n < (SELECT max(n) FROM evenfib)
)

SELECT id, SUM(prev_n)::INT
FROM fibonacci, evenfib
WHERE prev_n % 2 = 0
  AND prev_n < evenfib.n
GROUP BY id;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZDWDNYl))</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with that for about 3-4 hours and you saved me with that beatiful and simple solution, I edited it a bit to get a more suitable output in 2 columns 
(`n` from evenfib and `result` as sum of the evens to the corresponding limit)